# Will DeleteManyAsync lock MongoDB collection while deleting documents?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to use **DeleteManyAsync** method to delete multiple documents. I will encounter big collections being deleted. In the meantime I would like my new documents to be inserted. I would like to know if my **database collection** will be **locked** when DeleteManyAsync is fired.

This is the code I want to use :

```
 List<MyDocument> list= new List<MyDocument>();
 var filter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.In("_id", vl.Select(i => i.InternalId));
 await _context?.MyDocuments?.DeleteManyAsync(filter);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongo db locks are a low level concern and are handled at the database server level. You, as a programmer writing a client application using the driver, do not need to concern yourself about the database locks too much.

What I'm trying to say is that when using the C# driver you won't notice any kind of issue related to concurrent write operations executed on the same collection. Locks are handled by the storage engine, not by the driver used at the client application level.

If you check [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb) you can read that, in case of conflicting write operations on the same collection, the storage engine will retry the operation at the server level:

> When the storage engine detects conflicts between two operations, one will incur a write conflict causing MongoDB to transparently retry that operation

So, again, the concurrency issues are handled at the server level.

Consider that if you need your application to be highly scalable you should design your system in order to avoid as much as possible concurrent write operations on the same collection. As I said above, locks are handled by the storage engine in order to preserve the correctness of your data, but locks can reduce the overall scalability of your system. So, if scalability is critical in your scenario, you should carefully design your system and avoid contention of resources at the database level as much as possible.

**At the client application level you just need to decide whether or not retrying on a failed write operation**.

Sometimes you can safely retry a failed operation, some other times you can't (e.g.: in some cases you will endup having duplicate data at the database level. A good guard against this is using unique indexes).

As a rule of thumb, **idempotent write operations can safely be retried in case of a failure** (because applying them multiple times does not have any side effect). Put another way, strive to have idempotent write operations as much as possible: this way you are always safe retrying a failed write operation.

If you need some guidance about the mongo C# driver erorr handling, you can take a look to [this documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/error_handling/)

### Update 25th July 2020

Based on the author comment, it seems that the main concern is not the actual database locking strategy, but the delete performances instead.

In that case I would proceed in the following manner:

- always prefer a command performing a single database roundtrip (such as `deleteMany`) over issuing multiple single commands (such as `deleteOne`). By doing a single roundtrip you will minimize the latency cost and you will perform a single database command. It's simply more efficient
- when you use a `deleteMany` command **be sure to always filter documents by using a proper index**, so that collection scan is avoided when finding the documents to be deleted
- if you measure and you are **sure** that your bottleneck is the `deleteMany` speed, considere comparing the performances of `deleteMany` command with the one of an equivalent [bulk write operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-deleteonemany). I never tried that, so I have no idea about the actual speed comparison. My feeling is that probably there is no difference at all, because I supsect that under the hood `deleteMany` performs a bulk write. I have no clue on that, this is just a feeling.
- consider changing your design in order to exploit the [TTL index feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) for an automatic deletion of the documents when some sort of expiration criteria is satisfied. This is not always possible, but it can be handy when applicable.
- if you perform the delete operation as part of some sort of cleanup task on the data, consider scheduling a job performing the data cleanup operation on a regular basis, **but outisde of the business hours of your users**.

Comment: Thank you for the informative reply. Very helpful. In my case I was just worried that it may take some time to delete objects if I use DeleteManyAsync. In the meantime if I have an insert it won't appear in db(because of being locked). Thats why I was wondering if I should loop every element I want to delete or delete everything at once.

Comment: @mike I have updated my answer to touch on the point that you have highlighted in the comment.